# Can someone help me learn how to covert this php CURL to Python Requests

Tags: python, php, curl, python-requests

so if someone can help me convert the following php curl oriented into python using requests i have no idea where to start.

```
$data = [
        'username' => "email@email.com"
    ];

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.dnbhoovers.com/api/auth/login-details");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`enter code here`
$output = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));


$data = [
    'logonId' => $output->UserID,
    'password' => "password"
];
```

Comment: Maybe you could start by reading the documentation of the Python requests module?

Comment: The requests module is pretty easy to use, take a look at the documentation. Stack Overflow is not meant to be a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Thi could be helpful, you need to take a look into requests documentation

```
import requests

url = "https://app.dnbhoovers.com/api/auth/login-details"
data = {"username": "email@email.com"}
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, data = data, headers=headers) 

print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [request](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). First install the package e.g. via `pip install requests`.

Your example request then would be

```
import json
import requests

url = "https://app.dnbhoovers.com/api/auth/login-details"
data = {
    "username": "email@email.com"
}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data))

print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```